# SSIS - Loading Multiple Excel Files : First file messes up, rest are correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, ssms

So  I've been banging my head trying to figure this out. I have a folder with a bunch of Excel files with the same data structure. I am trying to import them into SSMS via  SSIS.

Now, I am able to get every file in perfectly EXCEPT the first. The problem is the derived column. I have 1 column in the Excel called Title. It contains a person's title and department. I use the Derived Column transformation to split it into a column called Designation and Department.

Every file works perfectly except the very first one. The first file leaves all the Designations blank and fills them into Department, but every other file does not do that and works perfectly.

Also, I enable the data viewer right before the data is pushed into the database and even in the data viewer the data is correct! Somehow the data is being mangled between SSIS and SSMS.

Oh and lastly, if I run the Data Flow Task without the For Each Loop, it works fine. I tried analyzing the variable in the For Each Loop but I don't see anything wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Control Flow]

[image: Data Flow Task]

[image: Data Viewer]

[image: SSMS]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was being caused by the derived columns being after the data conversion. I guess the conversion needs to happen after the derived split.